# asp.net viewstate security

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Is asp.net viewstate by EnableViewStateMac="True" is 100% secure?
I means, it's not important for me that user decode the viewstate content and see the values.
the thing that is important is tamper proof.
Can user change a value (for example an ID) and post back the page ?

Thank you very much for your feedbacks.

Answer (score 3):

Viewstate is tamper resistant, but not tamper proof.  This MSDN article talks about it (Threat #2)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff797918.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is on your page and sent to the client can be tampered with. This includes the viewstate that is passed on. Always validate input coming from a postback afterwards. Never assume that some identifier (for example) you sent to the client hasn't been changed before posting it back.

If you want to remember values, use server-side memory, such as the Session state.